# Efeito Pulse não trabalha corretamente quando tem 2 elementos

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, svg

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     xml:space="preserve">
     <g>
     <circle class="pulse" fill="none" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-miterlimit="5" cx="40" cy="40" r="2" />
    <circle class="" fill="#FF9C00" cx="40" cy="40" r="2" />
    </g>

    <g>
     <circle class="pulse" fill="none" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-miterlimit="5" cx="65" cy="65" r="2" />
    <circle class="" fill="#FF9C00" cx="65" cy="65" r="2" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

E o efeito:

```
@-webkit-keyframes svg_pulse {
     0% {
        -webkit-transform: matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0);
        stroke-width: 1;
        opacity: 1;
     }

     50% {
        opacity: 1;
     }
     100% {
        -webkit-transform: matrix(4,0,0,4,-120,-120);
        stroke-width: 0.25;
        opacity: 0;
     }
}

.pulse {
    -webkit-animation: svg_pulse 1s ease;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Em funcionamento: https://jsfiddle.net/4ej6msb9/1/

O problema é que o **pulse** funciona corretamente no primeiro `<circle>` mas no segundo, ao invés de funcionar corretamente, ele joga o pulse para baixo toda vez que pulsa. Não entendo o porque disso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transformação ocorre, por default, em relação à *origem das coordenadas DO SVG* (ponto 0,0 do SVG - canto superior esquerdo). Como o círculo não está na origem, você compensou movendo a origem durante a transformação (através de um *translate* simples -últimos dois parâmetros de `matrix()`). O problema é que são dois os círculos e eles estão em coordenadas diferentes. Para obter o efeito desejado neste caso, você teria que mover as duas origens e os valores seriam diferentes.

A solução mais simples é reposicionar a origem de coordenadas para cada transformação no centro do círculo correspondente. Isto pode ser feito definindo `transform-origin: 50% 50%;` para `.pulse` e eliminando o translate:

```
@-webkit-keyframes svg_pulse {
     ...
     100% {
        -webkit-transform: matrix(4,0,0,4,0,0); /* remova o translate 120,120 */
        stroke-width: 0.25;
        opacity: 0;
     }
}

.pulse {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;  /* acrescente esta linha */
    -webkit-animation: svg_pulse 1s ease;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Você adicionalmente pode trocar o `matrix(a,0,0,a,0,0)` por `scale(a)` que é equivalente e deixa seu código mais legível:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(4);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ej6msb9/2/)